# What kind of study or training can "Ausbildung" refer to?

Tags: word-usage

From [*Die Zeit*](http://www.zeit.de/2014/42/schule-ausbildung-studium-orientierung/seite-8):

> Wenn jemand gern praktisch arbeitet und möglichst schnell berufstätig sein will, kann eine **Ausbildung** für ihn geeigneter sein als ein **Studium**.

I understand that **Studium** can only refer to studying in the university, but is it the case that **Ausbildung** can refer to any kind of study or training, including middle/high school (Hauptschule, Realschule, Gymnasium), university, or internship (Praktikum)? If so, does **Ausbildung** in the given sentence only refer to internship (Praktikum), and the reader has to infer that from context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ausbildung in this case refers to vocational training.

If you talk about schools, the expression is "schulische Ausbildung", in the context of universities you might use "universitäre Ausbildung". Both possible, but a bit stilted.

---

Short explanation for readers from other countries:
In Germany, we have a combined system of learning on the job plus specialized schools for the education future professionals. 
Random example: A teen wanting to become a baker would apply at a bakery for an apprenticeship and then work roughly half his time in this bakery to learn the hands-on part of the training, and attend "Berufsschule" (school for professionals) where he's taught the theoretical aspects of his choosen profession. Attendance to school is mandatory part of the education. Only after the final exam (again: part theoretical test, part hands-on test) he may call himself a baker. 
(This example is slightly simplified.)

Edit: This applies also to many professions, that would typically be taught at colleges in the US, e.g. nurses.

Comment: +1, see also http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_education_system

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt je nach Kontext eine strengere und weniger strenge Auslegung der Begriffe. Zur Unterscheidung des Berufsweges nach der Schule bedeutet (Berufs-)Ausbildung eine 2- bis 3-jährige Ausbildung in einem praktischen Beruf, oft im Handwerk aber auch Dienstleistungen, Handel.

Ausbildung ist aber auch die allgemeine Bezeichnung für das Erwerben von Kenntnissen und Fertigkeiten, beispielsweise die Schulung zur Bedienung eines speziellen Apparates.

> Herr Müller wurde an der X-61 ausgebildet.

Ähnlich verhält es sich mit dem Studium. Im engeren Sinne bezeichnet das nur die Ausbildung an einer (Fach-)Hochschule/Universität. Man kann den Begriff aber auf alle Phänomene ausdehnen, bei denen man sich wissenserwerbend einer Sache widmet.

> Frau Meier ist Hobbyfotografin und studiert stundenlang das Leben der Rotkehlchen.

Je praktischer die Tätigkeit, desto eher wird man von Ausbildung sprechen und je theoretischer desto eher von Studium. In vielen Studiengängen ist mit Ende des Studiums noch keine Berufsfertigkeit erreicht, so ist das Studium der Medizin alleine noch keine Ausbildung zum Arzt. Wenn es aber keiner weiteren Einweisung bedarf, um beruflich loszulegen, kann man auch sagen, man sei an der Uni ausgebildet worden, etwa zum Historiker.